# Validation of viewstate MAC failed, tried generating machine key

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

### Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or    cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

I've looked through countless of previous questions and I haven't managed to get it working.

I've edited my web.config file and included a generated key at no success.

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
 -->
<configuration>
<system.web>
<machineKey validationKey="E91A16E07A8D628F1F1397962336B0C63B6DC45B8EB3D16BBD5E5761DD8AE462C04C1CC215904FF0353E84EF8194B48682114C72CF8E10F5295E5ADF36DBC520" decryptionKey="EFA118DF00BFB8206F24A1BB4AF7D18FBD6A605B44789E9048D8127FFF950A09" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
<httpRuntime />
<pages enableViewStateMac="true" />

<customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

This happens when I postback to another page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using <form action="..."> to perform a cross-page post back, try changing your submit button to read <asp:Button runat="server" postbackurl="...">.  Using the PostBackUrl property is [the officially supported way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to perform a cross-page post back, as it sets a flag in the request telling the destination page to ignore the __VIEWSTATE field.

Comment: This worked, however I had already found a workaround. Will note for future reference though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem lies in the Application Pool of your website.Configure your website to use the proper .NET Framework version (i.e. v4.0) under the General section of the Application Pool related to your website.

Under the Process Model, set the Identity value to Network Service.Close the dialog box and right-click your website and select Advanced Settings... from the Manage Website option of the content menu. In the dialog box, under General section, make sure you have selected the proper name of the Application Pool to be used.

Your website should now run without any problem.Hope this helps you overcome this error.